# RMarkdown using readthedown template. self_contained: true seems do not work

Tags: r, r-markdown, rmdformats

I'm referring to the template **readthedown** provided by the package **rmdformats** version 1.0.4  executed by  R 4.2.1 on Windows 11

I'm running an old script with the following YAML section

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "SubTitle"
author: "Author"
date: "(`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %b, %Y')`)"
output:
  rmdformats::readthedown:
    toc_depth: 5
    self_contained: true
    thumbnails: false
    lightbox: true
    gallery: true
    highlight: tango
    css: custom.css
---
```

The compilation process reach the end without errors but generating the output file (Ex. **report.html**) and a related **folder** named for Ex. **report_files** that contain all the images generated run-time by the rmarkdown chunks.

A few version updates ago the image folder was not generated

The statement **self_contained: true** it seems by masked or unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the global option `cache` set as `TRUE` in your setup chunk, either remove that option (then it will default to `FALSE`) or set the option as `FALSE`.

Having `cache` set as `TRUE` is a possible reason to generate the folder containing necessary images.

Therefore, if you run the following reprex, you will see that no extra folder is created in your working directory.

**Reprex**

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "SubTitle"
author: "Author"
date: "(`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %b, %Y')`)"
output:
  rmdformats::readthedown:
    toc_depth: 5
    self_contained: true
    thumbnails: false
    lightbox: true
    gallery: true
    highlight: tango
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
## Global options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE)
```

## Some Plots

```{r}
plot(rnorm(50), runif(50))
```

```{r}
plot(rnorm(50), runif(50))
```

```{r}
plot(rnorm(50), runif(50))
```
````